# How to get hosts variables with Ansible?

Tags: python, ansible

Ansible: v2.3.0.0
Python: v2.7.12

---

The `hosts` file:

```
[server1]
192.168.0.1
```

At playbook, tried this way to get the IP value:

```
- debug:
    msg: "Host: {{ hostvars['server1'] }}"
```

It said `hostvars.HostVars` has no attribute `server1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`server1` is a group name in your example. If you want `server1` to be a host, define inventory like this:

```
[myservers]
server1 ansible_host=192.168.0.1
```